# Clicking of closing/dismissing ng-bootstrap modal causes page to be scrolled to the top

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am currently working with [Ng-Boostrap's modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples).

Within the modal, I have a Reactive Form.

For some reason, when I click the close button, submit button, or clicking outside of the modal area to close/dismiss the modal, it causes the page to be scrolled all the way to the top after the modal is closed.

May I know if anyone has faced a similar issue, and has a solution for it? I definitely do not want it to be scrolled to the top of the page.

Here is my code for the modal on my component.html:

```
<!--begin::Modal-->
<ng-template #content let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="product-allocation-settings">Product Allocation</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="productAllocationForm">
      <!-- other irrelevant form fields -->
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="d('Submit')">Submit</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<!--end::Modal-->
```

And on my component.ts, this handles the submission of the form within the modal. This closes the modal too.

```
this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'lg', centered: true }).result.then(() => {

}, (reason) => {
  if (reason === 'Submit') {
    this.save();
  }
});
```

I have tried the following solutions, but I do not seem to be having any luck.

1) [Prevent page scroll after click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697917/prevent-page-scroll-after-click)

2) [Prevent browser jump to top page when submit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612569/prevent-browser-jump-to-top-page-when-submit-the-form)

Comment: What is the content of your `save()` function? Does this submit the form? I've created [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uybeim?file=app/modal-basic.ts) (scroll down for the button to launch the modal) based on your code, but the page doesn't scroll when the modal is closed, suggesting it could be related to submitting/saving the form

Comment: @IanA Thanks for taking a look at this. In short, the `save()` function sends a POST request to the server. But I am starting to wonder if this is a CSS issue, as this modal is within a Material Tab (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs)..